# How to use MS GraphService client to use the access token for authentication

Tags: java, authorization, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to build a client system which fetches the inbox of the user emails in outlook. The requirement is that the system should ask the user to login through Outlook once to authenticate and it should be able to fetch the emails and other actions enables via graph API like reply, forward etc there after without any login prompt. For this I tried using the MS Graph SDK and chose the authorization code flow for the same . I followed the following steps

1. Requested an authorization code by using the link : [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read%20api%3A%2F%2F](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read%20api%3A%2F%2F)
2. I have stored this authorization code to the db and used the following snippet for authorization.

```
    final AuthorizationCodeCredential authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId("client id")
    .clientSecret("client secret") 
    .authorizationCode("authcode from the db for that user")
    .redirectUrl("http://localhost:8080/redirect/url")
    .build();
    
    final List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add("Mail.Send");
    scopes.add("offline_access");
    scopes.add("openid");
    
    final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, authCodeCredential);    
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();
    
    MessageCollectionPage messages = graphClient.me()
    .messages()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

3. This works the first time the fetched authorization code is fetched by user interaction , but when the same code is reused to avoid user interactions it throws the following

**AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.**

Does this mean that to make this flow work I have to request my users to login everytime for a single API call via graph client. Is there any way in which we can use the access code got in the AuthorizationCodeCredential and use it with GraphServiceClient to access microsoft Graph APIs using the SDK . Will hugely appreciate any kind of help on this. thank you

Comment: It seems that all your user interaction are realized in your java backend app, it's not recommended. For the backend application, it should use [client-credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) to do authentication for calling ms graph api.

Comment: Thanks for the response @TinyWang . But client-credential flow needs an admin consent , but my usecase is to get consent from the individual users and not on behalf of the organization as a whole.Is there any ways we can get only user level access rather than the organization admin level directly?

Comment: Basically, we used MSAL in the frontend application to let user sign in and app can obtain access token/ refresh token, then using access token to call the graph api. I'm not sure how you compose your frontend app, so pls refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) and choose a sample to follow up.

Comment: By the way, you're using ms graph api to get the input box content, so you can use graph client, you can also call the api by sending an http get request with an access token inside the request header. So when you got the access token, it means you can get the api.